# Make all uploaded files public?

Tags: file-sharing, cloud-storage, owncloud

I'm running a personal ownCloud instance, and I want to make all the files I push up to it public. I have nothing to hide, and I see the software as a better way to manage public downloads than just a directory and apache2.

Is there a way to allow all files to be available in the same directory structure (`mysite.com/owncloud/index.php/apps/files/download//myfile.txt`) rather than entering the GUI and making a share link?